# How to achieve below scenario, using RealityKit and RealityComposer Or use ARKit with SceneKit?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit, realitykit

Using ARKit on tap I am going to add an object (.scn file) in SceneView and perform actions like move, rotate and resize using Long Press, Pan gesture and Pinch gesture respectively. Now I add object in RealityComposer and add it in Xcode and using RealityKit I want to perform same actions on object like move, rotate and resize using Long Press, Pan gesture and Pinch gesture respectively then how to achieve it using RealityKit and RealityComposer Or use ARKit with SceneKit?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this myself, but it seems that you would do something like this:

`arView.installGestures([.rotation, .translation, .scale], for: yourEntity)`

where `arView` is an your ARView instance and `yourEntity` is the entity you're trying to transform.

[Apple Documentation - installGestures(_:for:))](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/arview/3255312-installgestures)